# SelectedValue of DataBound combo box setting selectedValue to null

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

I'm trying to create an interface for some legacy DB tables that have a bit of an odd structure, but I'm getting stuck on setting a selectedValue of a combo box.

```
cboSubProject.Visible = true;
cboSubProject.DataSource = linqDB.SubProjects;
cboSubProject.ValueMember = "intSubProjectKey";
cboSubProject.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
```

I later try to set the Selected value of the combo box as follows:

```
cboSubProject.SelectedValue = record.subProjectKey;
```

I'm not using a subProject entity as at this point I dont have one in hand, just it's intSubProjectKey from another object, But I can't even set the selected value as follows:

```
cboSubProject.SelectedValue = 3;
```

I can however query the linqDB.SubProjects and get the row with the record.subProjectKey value, but I was hoping to just use the values I have in hand, and considering the final result has the cboSubProject.SelectedValue equal to 3. Any clarification will be helpful.

NOTE: 
I have try moving the value and display members above the dataSource line, to no avail.

Comment: What happens when you assign the value to `SelectedValue`?

Comment: The only thing I've gotten to work with SelectedValue is: `cboSubProject.SelectedValue = linqDB.SubProjects.First(s => s.intSubProjectKey == record.subProjectKey).intSubProjectKey;`
but the value is the same as record.subProjectKey,(in this case both are 3), I was just curious why I can't just set the value. 

I have other Combo Boxes that basically do the same thing.